# Gcloud command not running on gitlab ci yml warning: here-document at line ted by end-of-file (wanted `EOF') /bin/bash: : EOF: command not found

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab-ci, gcloud

I am getting the following error when I run the below gcloud command in gitlab-ci.yml

`` /bin/bash: line 152: warning: here-document at line 152 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF') /bin/bash: line 152: EOF: command not found ``

````
- gcloud compute ssh --zone asia-southeast1-b instance-1 --command="bash -s" <<-EOF
     fuser -k 8080/tcp
     nohup java -jar /home/XXX/XXX-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
     EOF```
````

Answer (score 0):

Both gitlab and heredoc syntax (`<<-EOF`) have specific whitespace requirements that clash.

Luckily, yaml allows multiline commands as long as the indentation is maintained, so heredoc notation is not needed. This could be done as follows:

```
  - gcloud compute ssh --zone asia-southeast1-b instance-1 --command="bash -s
    fuser -k 8080/tcp;
    nohup java -jar /home/XXX/XXX-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Note that semicolons have also been introduced between the commands.

Comment: It works in the sense that GitLab doesn’t give error. But when I tried to set env variables using export varA=val to set it in remote server. It didn’t really set those variables. Any idea why that didn’t work ?